# Extracting the year from an 8 digit int (ddmmyyyy) in SAS

Tags: sas

I have an 8 digit date of birth (e.g., 19860710). How can I extract the just the 4 digits of the year portion and store it in a new variable (e.g., 1986) in SAS?

Comment: `int(19860710 / 10000)`?

Answer (score 1):

i suggest when dealing with dates to (nearly) always to convert to SAS dates. You will save a lot of headache that way.

```
data wanted; 
    sas_date=input('19860710', yymmdd8.);
    Sae_year=year(sas_date);
    call symput('Year_mac_var', Sae_year);
run;

%put &Year_mac_var.; 
1986
```

You can do this via Substring Proc sql or by arithmetic ways. This is just what I prefer.

Answer (score 1):

Using substring:

```
num=19860710;  /*Date as Numeric*/
txt=put(num,8.); /*Change Numeric to Char*/
year=substr(txt,1,4);
```

Or

```
year=substr("19860710",1,4);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data _null_;
 date=19860710;
 year=year(input(put(date,8.),yymmdd8.));
 put year;
run;
```